# Rehinkdb, get the rows number after changes()

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I am new in Rethinkdb and the ReQL api. And I want to know what is the best way of getting the count() of a table after insert() a new row?

This is my actual javascript implementation, but I think it can be improved

`r.table('likes')
    .changes()
    .run(conn)
    .then(cursor => 
        cursor.each(() => {
            r.table('likes')
            .count()
            .run(conn, (err, result) => console.log(result))
        })
    })`

Then when I add new row

`r.table('likes')
    .insert({ time: (new Date()).getTime() })
    .run(conn)`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why not have a change feed for count? e.g. `r.table('likes').count().changes()`

Comment: You cannot get the changefeed after count() unfortunately :(
"However, since the stream produced by changes has no ending, commands that need to consume the entire stream before returning (such as reduce or count) cannot." (https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/changes/)